# Как осуществить взаимодействие двух клиентов на сервере?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, websocket

Всем привет! Пишу программу, в которой имеется сервер, который ожидает подключения клиентов и записывает Connection List подключившихся клиентов (сокетов). Нужно, чтобы затем сервер принимал сообщения от одного клиента и пересылал другому клиенту (определенному). т.е как организовать эти рабочие пары? (клиент1-клиент2; клиент3-клиент4)

Клиент и сервер написаны на Java...

Comment: Вам надо как-то идентифицировать коннекшены, обычно это происходит после логина. И при посылке сообщения указывать в нём кому именно оно предназначается.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите простой класс, если еще не сделали - UserConnection, в котором будут методы отправки и передачи. Примерно будет выглядеть так:
1) клиент( сокет ) отправляет запрос серверу с информацией о сообщении : кому он хочет отправить сообщение и сам текст сообщения
2)сервер получает сообщение от клиента с ip1, которое он хочет отправить клиенту с ip2 и находит в ConnectionList Connection, у которого ip = ip2, и через output поток отправляет нужный текст.